# C++: Resize 2D vector

Tags: c++, windows, matrix

I am getting the error

```
"The expression needs to be a constant"
```

when I try to do this:

```
float mat1[m_Floats.size()][iNumClass];
```

Can I trick the compiler (VS2010) into compiling this anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only C99 specify dynamic array allocation (i.e. where size is known only at compile time). Maybe there is a MSVC extension to the standard, but you should go the canonical way in creating the array of pointers and each float subarray using `new`, like in:

```
float **mat1 = new float*[m_Floats.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < m_Floats.size(); ++i) {
    mat1[i] = new float[iNumClass];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, instead of "tricking the compiler", you can dynamically allocate your matrix with the operator `new`

Comment: Can you post example code on how this is done? I have always avoid "new".

Answer (score 0):

No.  The size of a declared array needs to be known at compile time.  The value of `m_Floats.size()` depends on how many members are in that object.

If you need to allocate arrays with variable size, you'll need to handle it yourself with `new` or some appropriate classes/methods that encapsulate that for you.